# How to use preg_match with file extension in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, preg-match, ico

I'm looking for a file which name is like this string: `.047b2edb.ico`

I am not sure how to add "`ico`" extension to my `preg_match` function.

```
[.a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

This is my whole code. With this code I can't find a file with name .62045303.ico where is the problem ?

```
<?php
$filepath = recursiveScan('/public_html/');

function recursiveScan($dir) {
    $tree = glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/*');
    if (is_array($tree)) {
        foreach($tree as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                //echo $file . '<br/>';
                recursiveScan($file);
            } elseif (is_file($file)) {
               if (preg_match_all("(/[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico/)", $file )) {
                   //echo $file . '<br/>';
                   unlink($file);
               }

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico
```

will do it.

Explanation:

```
[.a-zA-Z0-9]  match a character which is a dot, a-z, A-Z or 0-9
+             match one or more of these characters
\.ico         match literally dot followed by "ico".
              the backslash is needed to escape the dot as it is a metacharacter
```

Example:

```
$string = 'the filenames are .asdf.ico and fdsa.ico';

preg_match_all('/[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .asdf.ico
            [1] => fdsa.ico
        )

)
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+ how to fix this ?

Comment: @AdamKowalski: You haven't put delimiters arround the regex!

Comment: What delimiters ?

Comment: @AdamKowalski: Regex delimiter (ie. `/[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico/`)

Comment: dosen't work. My code:   if (preg_match("/[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico/", $file )) {

Comment: @AdamKowalski: This peace of code is correct. You have an error elsewhere. Edit your question and add relevant code (ie. the smalest peace that produces the error)

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Could You check my question again bcs the preg_match dosent work for me. The ([.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.ico) dosent cant find the file with name: .05becc52.ico

Comment: use only preg_match() in your script. you are looking for one match only. preg_match() returns true if found and false if not found. that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to match, this might be good for you

`([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.ico)`

Comment: There're no needs to escape dot inside a character class.